# From Transistor to Gates

Tags: transistors

Does anyone know any links, books, tutorials etc. that will help me better understand how transistors are used to design gates/functions?

[Here is a link](http://www.cs.bu.edu/~best/courses/modules/Transistors2Gates/) that does a good job of explaining the basics.
Looking for more complex examples that are similar to the link above

Comment: Jan Rabaey's widely-used textbook *Digital Integrated Circuits* covers this material and is available as a free e-book: http://www.scribd.com/doc/2190480/Digital-Integrated-Circuits-by-Rabaey

Answer (score 3):

[Here](http://www.transistor-clock.com./index_002.htm) is a complete digital clock made entirely using discrete transistors.

It's sold as a kit, and the [instruction manual](http://www.transistor-clock.com./tranmanual.pdf) is quite good, with extensive breakdowns of the logic sections, oscilloscope drawings, and a full schematic.

---

[Play-Hookey.com](http://www.play-hookey.com/digital/) is another great resource for understanding how complex gate functions are constructed from simple ones. They have most of the standard logic set, and it's all done with little interactive javascripts, so you can actually change the inputs, and watch the output change.

Answer (score 2):

The link you gave explains how gates can be made from transistors.

Next you don't think about transistors any more, but about gates as building blocks for more complex logical functions like multiplexers, demultiplexers, 1-bit-adders, flip-flops, latches and clocked registers. Most any book about digital circuits will contain an explanation fo this level.

The next step is to take those as building blocks and build an ALU, ROM, RAM, datapath, etc. This level can be found in books about CPU design, for instance Hennessy & Patterson.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [all about circuits](http://www.allaboutcircuits.com/) they have great explanations on most topics in electronics.